# setValue on combodate.js based ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the [combodate](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) jQuery library. How can I set the value in the field when I get data from AJAX? In the documentation there is no example of this. I tried `$(selector).val('var from ajax')` but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Selesai</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="tanggal_selesai" class="form-control combodate " type="text">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.combodate').combodate({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',    
   template: 'DD / MM / YYYY   HH : mm',    
   value: null, 
   minYear: 2015,    
   maxYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
   yearDescending: true,
   minuteStep: 1,
   secondStep: 1,   
   firstItem: 'empty',
   errorClass: null,   
   customClass: 'form-control',
   roundTime: true,   
   smartDays: false
});

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('members/it/request/ajax_edit/') ?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (response) {
        $('[name="id"]').val(response.ID_REQUEST);
        $('[name="nama"]').val(response.ID_KARYAWAN);
        $('[name="tanggal_persetujuan"]').val(response.TANGGAL_PERSETUJUAN);
        $('[name="tanggal_terima"]').val(response.TANGGAL_TERIMA);
        $('[name="perkiraan_selesai"]').val(response.PERKIRAAN_SELESAI);
        $('[name="tanggal_selesai"]').val(response.TANGGAL_SELESAI);
        $('[name="pelaksana"]').val(response.PELAKSANA);
        $('[name="keluhan"]').val(response.KELUHAN);
        $('[name="catatan"]').val(response.CATATAN);
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Customer Data'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can use the `setValue()` method:

> Sets new value. Value can be javascript Date() object or string in options.format.

```
$('[name="tanggal_selesai"]').combodate('setValue', response.TANGGAL_SELESAI).
```